# Количество отображаемых спрайтов в несколько раз больше, чем есть на самом деле

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я новичок, пытаюсь сделать игру на pygame. В моей программе должно быть 3 уровня, каждый из которых переключается последовательно. Однако, у меня возникает проблема - с каждым уровнем количество врагов умножается в прогрессии (на первом уровне всё нормально, на втором - в 2 раза больше, чем должно быть, а на третьем аж 3 босса). Знаю, код далеко не чистый, да и картинки не могу отправить, но, пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка.

```
import os
import random
import sys
import pygame

CAN_ATTACK = 10
MOVE = 10

pygame.init()
mixer.init()
size = w, h = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('The Lord of Hell')
pygame.time.set_timer(CAN_ATTACK, 2000)
pygame.time.set_timer(MOVE, 5000)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey == -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    else:
        image = image.convert_alpha()
    return image

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def show_rules():
    screen2 = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    image2 = load_image('mountains.png')
    screen2.blit(image2, (0, 0))
# некоторое оформление
    running3 = True
    pygame.display.flip()
    while running3:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    main()
                    return

def start_screen():
    image = load_image('fon.png')
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (800, 600))
    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
# оформление
    cursor = Cursor()
    all_sprites.add(cursor)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        cursor.move_up()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        cursor.move_down()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        if cursor.rect.y == 245:
                            cursor.kill()
                            return
                        elif cursor.rect.y == 345:
                           show_rules()
                        else:
                            terminate()
# оформление
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
def win_screen():
    screen4 = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    image4 = load_image('fon.jpg')
    screen4.blit(image4, (0, 0))
# оформление
    running4 = True
    pygame.display.flip()
    while running4:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                main()
                return
class Heart(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x):
        global hearts
        super().__init__(hearts)
        self.image = load_image('heart.png', -1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = pos_x, 10

class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        global all_sprites
        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        self.image = load_image('sword.png', -1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = 65, 245

    def move_up(self):
        if self.rect.y != 245:
            self.rect.y -= 100

    def move_down(self):
        if self.rect.y != 445:
            self.rect.y += 100


def load_level(filename):
    filename = 'data/' + filename
    with open(filename, 'r') as mapFile:
        level_map = [line.strip() for line in mapFile]
        return level_map


def level_generate(level):
    new_player, x, y, return_level = None, None, None, []
    global count
    if '~' in level[1]:
        for y in range(len(level)):
            return_level.append([])
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == '2':
                    print(x, y)
                if level[y][x] == '@':
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES['s'], x, y, True)
                    return_level[-1].append(0)
                    new_player = Character(x, y)
                elif level[y][x] != 'm':
                    if level[y][x] != 's':
                        return_level[-1].append(-1)
                        if level[y][x] == 'k':
                            global key
                            key = Tile(TILE_IMAGES[level[y][x]], x, y, False)
                        else:
                            Tile(TILE_IMAGES[level[y][x]], x, y, False)
                    else:
                        return_level[-1].append(0)
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES[level[y][x]], x, y, True)
                else:
                    count += 1
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES['s'], x, y, True)
                    return_level[-1].append(0)
                    Nps(x, y)
    elif 'w' in level[0]:
        for y in range(len(level)):
            return_level.append([])
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == '@':
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES2['f'], x, y, True)
                    new_player = Character(x, y)
                elif level[y][x] != 'x':
                    if (level[y][x] != 'v' or level[y][x] != 'r' or
                            level[y][x] != 'f'):
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES2[level[y][x]], x, y, False)
                    else:
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES2[level[y][x]], x, y, True)
                else:
                    count += 1
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES2['f'], x, y, True)
                    Nps(x, y)
    else:
        for y in range(len(level)):
            return_level.append([])
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == '@':
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES3['s'], x, y, True)
                    return_level[-1].append(0)
                    new_player = Character(x, y)
                elif level[y][x] != 'm':
                    if level[y][x] != 's':
                        return_level[-1].append(-1)
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES3[level[y][x]], x, y, False)
                    else:
                        return_level[-1].append(0)
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES3[level[y][x]], x, y, True)
                else:
                    Tile(TILE_IMAGES3['s'], x, y, True)
                    return_level[-1].append(0)
                    count += 1
                    Boss(x, y)
    return new_player, x, y, return_level


class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tile_image, pos_x, pos_y, can_move):
        global tiles_group, all_sprites
        super().__init__(tiles_group, all_sprites)
        self.image = tile_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(tile_width * pos_x, tile_height * pos_y)
        self.move = can_move

    def can_move(self):
        if self.move:
            return True

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        global player_group, all_sprites
        super().__init__(player_group, character_group, all_sprites)
        self.hp = 10
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.fl = True
        self.ind_x = 0
        self.ind_y = 0
        self.move = (0, 0)
        self.animation = animations['stay']
        self.image = self.animation.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(pos_x * tile_width, pos_y * tile_height)

    def right_attack(self, direction):
        attack.play()
        if self.fl:
            self.animation = AnimatedSprite(load_image("Download57453.png", (0, 0, 0)), 8, 33, -16, -8, True)
            self.image = self.animation.image
            self.rect.x -= 60
            self.ind_x = 60
            Shell(self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y + 15, 'fireball', direction, player_group)
            self.fl = False

    def left_attack(self, direction):
        attack.play()
        if self.fl:
            self.animation = AnimatedSprite(load_image("Download57453.png", (0, 0, 0)), 8, 33, -64, -56, True)
            self.image = self.animation.image
            self.rect.x -= 60
            self.ind_x = 60
            Shell(self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y + 15, 'fireball', direction, player_group)
            self.fl = False

    def up_attack(self, direction):
        attack.play()
        if self.fl:
            self.animation = AnimatedSprite(load_image("Download57453.png", (0, 0, 0)), 24, 20, -164, -140, True, True)
            self.image = self.animation.image
            self.rect.y -= 40
            self.ind_y = 40
            Shell(self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y + 15, 'fireball', direction, player_group)
            self.fl = False

    def down_attack(self, direction):
        attack.play()
        if self.fl:
            self.animation = AnimatedSprite(load_image("Download57453.png", (0, 0, 0)), 24, 20, -68, -48, True, True)
            self.image = self.animation.image
            Shell(self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y + 15, 'fireball', direction, player_group)
            self.fl = False


    def update(self, flag=None):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            self.kill()
            self.fl = False
        if flag:
            self.fl = True
        self.animation.update()
        self.image = self.animation.image
        if self.move != (0, 0):
            if self.move == (5, 0):
                self.animation = animations['right']
            elif self.move == (-5, 0):
                self.animation = animations['left']
            elif self.move == (0, 5):
                self.animation = animations['down']
            elif self.move == (0, -5):
                self.animation = animations['up']
            self.rect.x += self.move[0]
            self.rect.y += self.move[1]
            self.animation.update()
            self.image = self.animation.image
        if self.move == (0, 0) and self.animation.die():
            self.rect.x += self.ind_x
            self.rect.y += self.ind_y
            self.ind_x, self.ind_y = 0, 0
            player.animation = animations['stay']
            self.image = self.animation.image

class Nps(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__((nps_group, all_sprites))
        self.hp = 3
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.ind_x = 0
        self.ind_y = 0
        self.way = []
        self.move = (0, 0)
        self.fl = True
        self.animation = animations_nps['stay']
        self.image = self.animation.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(pos_x * tile_width, pos_y * tile_height)

    def update(self, flag=None):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            self.kill()
            global count
            count -= 1
            self.fl = False
        if flag:
            self.fl = True
        self.animation.update()
        self.image = self.animation.image
        if self.rect.x == player.rect.x and self.rect.y > player.rect.y:
            self.up_attack((0, -1))
        elif self.rect.x == player.rect.x and self.rect.y < player.rect.y:
            self.down_attack((0, 1))
        elif self.rect.y == player.rect.y and self.rect.x > player.rect.x:
            self.left_attack((-1, 0))
        elif self.rect.y == player.rect.y and self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
            self.right_attack((1, 0))
        elif self.move != (0, 0):
            if self.move == (4, 0):
                self.animation = animations_nps['right']
            elif self.move == (-4, 0):
                self.animation = animations_nps['left']
            elif self.move == (0, 4):
                self.animation = animations_nps['down']
            elif self.move == (0, -4):
                self.animation = animations_nps['up']
            self.rect.x += self.move[0]
            self.rect.y += self.move[1]
            self.animation.update()
            self.image = self.animation.image
        elif self.move == (0, 0) and self.animation.die():
            self.rect.x += self.ind_x
            self.rect.y += self.ind_y
            self.ind_x, self.ind_y = 0, 0
            player.animation = animations_nps['stay']
            self.image = self.animation.image

    # разные атаки

class Boss(Nps):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__(pos_x, pos_y)
        self.hp = 20
        Nps((self.rect.x // tile_width) + 1, self.rect.y // tile_height)
        Nps((self.rect.x // tile_width) - 1, self.rect.y // tile_height)


class Shell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, type, direction, no_targ):
        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.no_targ = no_targ
        if direction == (-1, 0):
            image = pygame.transform.rotate(shells[type], 180)
        elif direction == (0, 1):
            image = pygame.transform.rotate(shells[type], 270)
        elif direction == (0, -1):
            image = pygame.transform.rotate(shells[type], 90)
        else:
            image = shells[type]
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(pos_x + direction[0] * tile_width,
                                               pos_y + direction[1] * tile_height)
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.direction[0] * 10, self.direction[1] * 10)
        for i in character_group:
            if self.rect.colliderect(i) and i not in self.no_targ:
                i.hp -= 1
                print(i.hp)
                self.kill()

class AnimatedSprite():
    def __init__(self, sheet, columns, rows, cut_x=None, cut_y=None, die=False, speed=False):
        if die:
            self.count = 0
        else:
            self.count = None
        self.speed = speed
        self.cut_x = cut_x
        self.cut_y = cut_y
        self.frames = []
        self.cut_sheet(sheet, columns, rows)
        self.cur_frame = 0
        self.image = self.frames[self.cur_frame]

    def cut_sheet(self, sheet, columns, rows):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, sheet.get_width() // columns,
                                sheet.get_height() // rows)
        for j in range(rows):
            for i in range(columns):
                frame_location = (self.rect.w * i, self.rect.h * j)
                self.frames.append(sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(
                    frame_location, self.rect.size)))
        if not self.speed:
            self.frames = self.frames[self.cut_x:self.cut_y]
        else:
            self.frames = self.frames[self.cut_x:self.cut_y:3]

    def update(self):
        self.cur_frame = (self.cur_frame + 1) % len(self.frames)
        self.image = self.frames[self.cur_frame]
        if self.count is not None:
            self.count += 1

    def die(self):
        if self.count is not None:
            if self.count >= 8:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True

# класс камеры

shells = {'fireball': pygame.transform.scale(load_image('fireball.png', (0, 0, 0)), (50, 30))}
animations = {...}

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_image = load_image('wizard.png')
player_image = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, (50, 50))
tiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
nps_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
character_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
hearts = pygame.sprite.Group()
nps_move = [(4, 0), (-4, 0), (0, 4), (0, -4)]
player = None
tile_width = tile_height = 50
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
key = None
count = None
flag = True
def show_level1():
    global all_sprites, nps_groupm, character_group, player_group,\
        hearts, player_image, tiles_group, player, clock, key, count, flag
    count = 0
    key_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player, level_x, level_y, level = level_generate(load_level('level1.txt'))
    total_w = level_x * tile_width
    total_h = level_y * tile_width
    camera = Camera(camera_func, total_w, total_h)
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == CAN_ATTACK:
                character_group.update('flag')
            if event.type == MOVE:
                for i in nps_group:
                    i.move = random.choice(nps_move)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.left_attack((-1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.right_attack((1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.up_attack((0, -1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, -5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.down_attack((0, 1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, 5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if (player.rect.x // 50 == 7 and
                            player.rect.y // 50 == 17):
                        key.kill()
                        Tile(TILE_IMAGES['s'], 8, 18, True)
                        key = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                        key.image = load_image('key.png', -1)
                        key.rect = key.image.get_rect()
                        key.rect.x, key.rect.y = 740, 10
                        get.play()
                        key.add(key_group)
                    if (player.rect.x // 50 == 22 and
                            player.rect.y // 50 == 18 and
                        key in key_group):
                        return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                player.move = (0, 0)
            if player.hp == 0:
                return -1
        all_sprites.update()
        camera.update(player)
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        screen.blit(player.image, camera.apply(player))
        for sprite in nps_group:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        hearts = pygame.sprite.Group()
        x = 10
        for i in range(player.hp):
            heart = Heart(x)
            heart.add(hearts)
            x += 30
        hearts.draw(screen)
        key_group.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(8)
        pygame.display.flip()

def show_level2():
    global all_sprites, nps_group, character_group, player_group, \
        hearts, player_image, tiles_group, player, clock, count
    for sprite in all_sprites:
        sprite.kill()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    count = 0
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    tiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    nps_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    character_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player, level_x, level_y, level = level_generate(load_level('level2.txt'))
    print(all_sprites, character_group, player, nps_group)
    total_w = level_x * tile_width
    total_h = level_y * tile_width
    camera = Camera(camera_func, total_w, total_h)
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == CAN_ATTACK:
                character_group.update('flag')
            if event.type == MOVE:
                for i in nps_group:
                    i.move = random.choice(nps_move)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.left_attack((-1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.right_attack((1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.up_attack((0, -1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, -5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.down_attack((0, 1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, 5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(player.rect.x // 50, player.rect.y // 50)
                    if (player.rect.x // 50 == 19 and player.rect.y // 50 == 5):
                        return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                player.move = (0, 0)
            if player.hp == 0:
                return -1
        all_sprites.update()
        camera.update(player)
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        screen.blit(player.image, camera.apply(player))
        for sprite in nps_group:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        nps_group.draw(screen)
        hearts = pygame.sprite.Group()
        x = 10
        for i in range(player.hp):
            heart = Heart(x)
            heart.add(hearts)
            x += 30
        hearts.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(8)
        pygame.display.flip()

def show_level3():
    global all_sprites, nps_group, character_group, player_group, \
        hearts, player_image, tiles_group, player, clock, count
    count = 0
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    tiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    nps_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    character_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    player, level_x, level_y, level = level_generate(load_level('level3.txt'))
    total_w = level_x * tile_width
    total_h = level_y * tile_width
    camera = Camera(camera_func, total_w, total_h)
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == CAN_ATTACK:
                character_group.update('flag')
            if event.type == MOVE:
                for i in nps_group:
                    i.move = random.choice(nps_move)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.left_attack((-1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.right_attack((1, 0))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.up_attack((0, -1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, -5)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if event.mod == 64:
                        player.down_attack((0, 1))
                    elif player.animation.die():
                        player.move = (0, 5)
                if count == 0:
                    return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                player.move = (0, 0)
            if player.hp == 0:
                return -1
        all_sprites.update()
        camera.update(player)
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        screen.blit(player.image, camera.apply(player))
        for sprite in nps_group:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
        hearts = pygame.sprite.Group()
        x = 10
        for i in range(player.hp):
            heart = Heart(x)
            heart.add(hearts)
            x += 30
        hearts.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(8)
        pygame.display.flip()


def main():
    start_screen()
    show_level1()
    show_level2()
    show_level3()
    win_screen()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы отрисовываете слайды на неочищенном экране. Нужно заливать screen цветом исходного фона каждый раз при обновлении кадра.
Там, где у вас строка `all_sprites.draw(screen)` в функции start_screen, перед ней добавьте:

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Это если вам нужно залить черным. В ином случае замените цвет заливки